# How to create a copy of a Linked List to another address in C?

Tags: c, list, linked-list, copy, singly-linked-list

Suppose you have a Linked List and **you want to make the different copy and add a number of elements to this list but you do not know about the number.** Each linked list must have a different address to change. The Linked List:

```
struct path {
   int node;
   struct path *next;
};
```

Each time I will send the start address of Linked List to the function with a value, **the function will make a copy of Linked List in another address and add the value at the END of the list (many times).**

I implemented the following to code to create and add new element on Linked List:

```
/* Head and Tail for Linked Lists */
struct path *pathHead = NULL;
struct path *pathTail = NULL;

void newPathElement(int node) {

struct path *rv = malloc(sizeof (struct path));
rv->node = node;

if (pathHead == NULL) {
    pathHead = rv;
    pathHead -> next = NULL;
    pathTail = pathHead;
} else {
    pathTail -> next = rv;
    pathTail = rv;
    pathTail -> next = NULL;
}
}
```

> Note I want to make different copies of a linked list. Each copy has its Head and Tail, they will be different for each copied list.

The function signature is the following signature:

```
struct path *copyPath(struct path *head, struct path *tail, int node){

}
```

Comment: Create a new, empty linked list. Loop over your first linked list, and add each element to the new list.

Comment: @Barmar I know it but I need help. I do not know how to I can do it. How to create new? with: `struct path *newPath = Null`

Comment: @SaeedRahmani are you able to create a simple list from scratch containing for example 3 nodes ?

Comment: How did you create the first linked list? Create the new linked list the same way.

Comment: Search for "how to implement a list in c" in your favorite search engine. Sample: https://www.google.com/search?ei=iR21WpG9LcGWtQWd5Z3gAw&q=how+to+implement+a+list+in+c&oq=how+to+implement+a+list+in+c&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i22i30k1l8.2547.2714.0.3658.2.2.0.0.0.0.78.153.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.152...0.0.jn9pKx6DYnA

Comment: You forgot to mention what you have coded so far and what your problem is.

Comment: Probably you worked to abstract the problem before posting your question here, but the job has not been well done, as the point is still difficult to get. I suggest to make a synthesis of the specific question and give more context details where they are necessary to understand the specific question.

Comment: @EmanueleDelGrande I edited it.

Comment: @EmanueleDelGrande The question is clear!

Comment: @Barmar I need make many different copies of the linked list with different Head andTail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We beginners should help each other.:)

In fact it is enough to write a function that appends a new node to a list or to incorporate its code to the function that copies a list.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct path 
{
    int node;
    struct path *next;
};

int append( struct path **head, int node )
{
    struct path *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct path ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        tmp->node = node;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}

struct path * copy( const struct path *source )
{
    struct path *destination = NULL;

    for ( ; source; source = source->next ) append( &destination, source->node );

    return destination;
}

void display( const struct path *head )
{
    for ( ; head; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", head->node );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct path *first_list = NULL;
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) append( &first_list, i );

    display( first_list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    struct path *second_list = copy( first_list );

    display( second_list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

You can make the function `copy` more efficient the following way

```
struct path * copy( const struct path *source )
{
    struct path *destination = NULL;

    for ( struct path **tmp = &destination; source; source = source->next ) 
    {
        append( tmp, source->node );
        tmp = &( *tmp )->next;
    }       

    return destination;
}
```

Comment: Every time the destination is different? It means I need a lot of different copy.

Comment: Your append() function is not efficient. You go through the entire list to append a new node. Using a tail pointer, you can immediately append to the list. Of course, you have to update the tail pointer afterwards...

Comment: @machine_1 When we run: `struct path *head = Null` is considered a new address? If I repeat this command 10 times all of them are different?

Comment: @saeed the head is modified once when calling the function append. Even if you called it multiple times, it wont modify it more than once.

Comment: @machine_1 I need a copy function to have different head and tail every time. for example, I have a list then I need a copy of it with new head an tail and an added node at the end of it. I will repeat this procedure many times.

Comment: Why have you de-selected the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167434/discussion-between-saeed-rahmani-and-machine-1).

Comment: @machine_1 You are wrong. The function append is efficient. You can just pass to the function a tail node if you want.

Comment: @vlad hmm, Interesting. But the name head makes the impression that it goes through the entire list.

Comment: @machine_1 It is a general function. You can pass a reference to any node to it. So it is only your personal problem. Moreover initiually a two-side list was not even mentioned in the question. So your comments do not make sense. Try to do something useful.

Comment: @vlad what two-side list? I never mentioned that.

Comment: @machine_1 A two sided singly linked list is a list that has a pointer to the ifirst node and has a pointer to the last node. Thta is it allows efficiently to insert a node at the beginning or at end of a singly-linked list.